# Presetting xkeyval keys to \thetitle or \theauthor

Tags: templates, xkeyval, titling

I'm writing a LaTeX template and am almost done (!!!) but I'm having a very hard time understanding `xkeyval`'s `\presetkeys` behaviour.
I've managed to set some defaults, but when it comes to setting them to `\theauthor` and `\thetitle` the keys are set to empty strings even though they're set after the `\author{}` and `\title{}` commands.

Here's a mwe:

#### my_mwe.cls

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ProvidesExplClass{my_mwe}
                  {2020/09/08}
                  {1.0}
                  {Minimal working example}

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \define@key{my_mwe} {author} [] {\def\my_mwe@author{#1}}
    \define@key{my_mwe} {title}  [] {\def\my_mwe@title{#1}}
    \presetkeys{my_mwe} {author}    {author={\theauthor}}
    \presetkeys{my_mwe} {title}     {title=\thetitle}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MWECommand}{O{}}{%
    \setkeys{my_mwe}{author, title, #1}%

    Here's~the~output:\\
    \my_mwe@title \\
    \my_mwe@author
}
```

#### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{my_mwe}

\usepackage{titling}
    \author{The poor crying author}
    \title{A sad mwe}

\begin{document}

\MWECommand%

\MWECommand[title=\thetitle, author=\theauthor]

\end{document}
```

What I'm expecting is that the basic call to `MWECommand` does the same as the argumented one, but instead the `\theauthor` and `\thetitle` strings are only printed in the second one.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask why you're using `xkeyval` instead of `l3keys` if you're using `expl3` (`xkeyval` having some hard to predict behaviours in corner cases)? Also, note that your macro names are a pretty wild mix and don't really follow LaTeX3 coding guidelines nor LaTeX2e style.

Comment: Also, your code assumes that `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` are defined, which isn't the case if you don't load `titling`, so you either should use `\@title` and `\@author` or `\RequirePackage{titling}` in your class!

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz I'm using `xkeyval` because I didn't know about keys until yesterday, so this is a noob question coming from a noob problem hahahah. I will look into the `l3keys` and fix the `titling` problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly setting the default value, which is used if you pass in the `author` or `title` keys without a value, to be empty with

```
\define@key{my_mwe}{author}[]{\def\my_mwe@author{#1}}
```

The value specified in brackets would be the default (which in this case is empty). The `\presetkeys` macro sets an initial value, that is a value which will be used if the key is not explicitly set at all.

Now in your macro you put `author, title, #1` in your `\setkeys`, so the default not the initial values will be used. And the defaults are empty.

So the easiest way would be to remove `author, title` from your definition (I've also removed the empty line in the definition, as I doubt you want to have a `\par` there, which would be the outcome):

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ProvidesExplClass{my_mwe}
                  {2020/09/08}
                  {1.0}
                  {Minimal working example}

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \define@key{my_mwe} {author} [] {\def\my_mwe@author{#1}}
    \define@key{my_mwe} {title}  [] {\def\my_mwe@title{#1}}
    \presetkeys{my_mwe} {author}    {author={\theauthor}}
    \presetkeys{my_mwe} {title}     {title=\thetitle}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MWECommand}{O{}}{%
    \setkeys{my_mwe}{#1}%
    Here's~the~output:\\
    \my_mwe@title \\
    \my_mwe@author
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a quick question. If I `\define@key` both `author` and `title` with a `[default-value]`, then I don't need to `\presetkeys` right? Can I just ignore the presetting in the future or is there an use case that's not covered in the definition?

Comment: @Groctel For performance reasons I wouldn't auto-add `author` and `title` into the `\setkeys` every time but use `\presetkeys`.

Comment: @Groctel note that if you're using `\theauthor` as the initial value with `\presetkeys` it doesn't matter what the current definition of `\theauthor` is, but only what the definition at use-time is, so as long as `\MWECommand` is used after `\author`, it'll work this way.